# How to specify packets in traceroute?

Tags: networking, packets

I reading the manual pages for help, but I didn't find a parameter that allows you to specify how many packets to send with the program?

Would appreciate tips from you guys, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would the `-q` parameter be what you're looking for?

> -q nqueries
>                 Sets the number of probe packets per hop. The default is 3.

If that's not what you want what exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Actually, it is, I just re-read the manual and saw that I missed it, thanks! :)